# Identify folders that do not have files with a certain string

Tags: linux, search, grep, find

First time here, so excuse me if I am not asking this in the correct way.
I have tried using grep -rL and variants of find and xargs, but nothing does quite what I am looking for. I would like to identify which subfolders (approx 500) do not have any file with the string "ObjectDate=true"  (they are all xml files).

Thank you!

Thank you for your help. Maybe I can put it better. I have approx 500 subfolders of one directory. There is no subfolders of these subfolders. Nearly all of the folders contain multiple xml files with the string "ObjectDate=true". I want to identify which subfolders do not contain any xml files with the string "ObjectDate=true".

The command below shows me what files do not contain the string. There are too many results from this so I would like to know what folders have no files that contain that string.

grep -rL "ObjectDate=true" /prod/he/log/dws/Usr/*/*.xml

Comment: That's a very poorly prepared question (note: the downvote isn't mine ;D). What's the directory structure? Do directories follow certain naming conventions?

Comment: Something like `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= -r -d $'\0' dir; do [[ -n $(find "$dir" -type f -name "*.xml" -exec grep -q "ObjectDate=true" {} \; -print -quit) ]] || echo "Missing $dir"; done` would probably work, though I haven't tested it, and it definitely isn't optimal. Also not sure `subfolders do not have` means in just the top level of the subfolder or anywhere, above assumes latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is:

```
find . -type d -print |
while IFS= read -r dir
do
    if ! grep -m1 -q "ObjectDate=true" "$dir"/*.xml
    then
        echo "$dir"
    fi
done
```

assuming no dir names with newlines in them.

Comment: Thank you, Please excuse my ignorance though. Can I run that command form the command line or so I need to put into a csh file or something like that?

Comment: You can run it from the command line or put it in a shell script. You should never write a shell script in csh though, google "csh why not".

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed - and I would have never figured it out myself.